# Edge labels writing over edge arrows in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

For my decision tree I need to place edge label nodes next to the nodes in GraphViz for readability, and i have tried to use `taillabel`  but it writes over the edge arrow.

For example the following code:

```
digraph workflow 
{ 
checkit -> doit [taillabel ="y";]; 
checkit -> dontdoit [taillabel="n";]; 
}
```

renders like this (I use GVedit : Graphviz 2.38.0, Graphvizversion 1.02) :

[image]

How can I ensure that edge labels such as 'y' do not write over the edge arrow ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [labelangle](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labelangle) and [labeldistance](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeldistance) attribute to control the precise position of taillabel or headlabel:

```
digraph workflow {
    checkit -> doit [
        taillabel ="y"
        labeldistance=2
        labelangle=330
    ]
    checkit -> dontdoit [
        taillabel="n"
        labeldistance=2
        labelangle=25
    ]
}
```

[image]